# SII (Suministro Inmediato de Información) Webservice en Facturas Recibidas

Tags: c#, aeat-sii

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo para enviar una factura recibida a la AEAT y al hacer la llamada al webservice de la AEAT me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> Información adicional: El tipo de contenido text/html del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (text/xml; charset=utf-8). Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente. Los primeros 1024 bytes de la respuesta fueron: '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" >"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html lang="es-ES">
> <head>
>     <title>Agencia Tributaria - Se ha producido un error</title>
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">       
> <link href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/css/xzhtcs04.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
> <script type="text/javascript">         function toggle()       {
>             var o=document.getElementById("AEAT_errores_tecnicos");             o.style.display=(o.style.display=='' || o.style.display=='none')?'block':'none';        }
>     </script>
> </head>
> <body>
> <div id="body">     <div id="header">   <div id="AEAT_header">    <div id="topIzquierda">
>         <div id="logoAEAT">
>             <ul>
>                 <li><a target="_self" href="https://www.agenciatributaria.gob.es"><span class="logoGobierno"></span></a>
>                 </li>
>                 <li><a target="_self" href="http://www.agenciatributaria.es"><span class="logoAEAT"></span></a>
>                 </li>           </ul>                   </div>
> ```

El ejemplo que hago es el siguiente

```
string cNomCer = "NOMBRE mi certificado correcto";
X509Certificate2 oCert = null;
var almCerts = Funciones.CreateX509Store();
List<X509Certificate2> certificados = Funciones.GetCertificatesList(almCerts);
oCert = Funciones.BuscarCertificado(cNomCer, certificados);

SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas servicio = new SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas();
servicio.Cabecera = new CabeceraSii();
servicio.Cabecera.IDVersionSii = VersionSiiType.Item06;
servicio.Cabecera.TipoComunicacion = ClaveTipoComunicacionType.A0;
servicio.Cabecera.Titular = new PersonaFisicaJuridicaESType();
servicio.Cabecera.Titular.NIF = "MICIF";
servicio.Cabecera.Titular.NombreRazon = "MI EMPRESA";

LRFacturasRecibidasType fac = new LRFacturasRecibidasType();
fac.PeriodoImpositivo = new RegistroSiiPeriodoImpositivo();
fac.PeriodoImpositivo.Ejercicio = "2017";
fac.PeriodoImpositivo.Periodo = TipoPeriodoType.Item05;

IDFacturaRecibidaType idFact = new IDFacturaRecibidaType(); //IDFACTURA

IDFacturaRecibidaTypeIDEmisorFactura emisorFactura = new IDFacturaRecibidaTypeIDEmisorFactura();
IDOtroType idOtro = new IDOtroType();
idOtro.CodigoPais = CountryType2.ES;                            //((CountryType2)(202)); //España
idOtro.IDType = PersonaFisicaJuridicaIDTypeType.Item02;
idOtro.ID = "46759200Q"; 
emisorFactura.Item = idOtro;

fac.IDFactura = new IDFacturaRecibidaType();
fac.IDFactura.IDEmisorFactura = emisorFactura;

fac.IDFactura.NumSerieFacturaEmisor = "SU FACTURA";
fac.IDFactura.FechaExpedicionFacturaEmisor = "04-05-2017";

fac.FacturaRecibida = new FacturaRecibidaType();
fac.FacturaRecibida.TipoFactura = ClaveTipoFacturaType.F1;
fac.FacturaRecibida.ClaveRegimenEspecialOTrascendencia = IdOperacionesTrascendenciaTributariaType.Item01;
fac.FacturaRecibida.ImporteTotal = "1210";
fac.FacturaRecibida.DescripcionOperacion = "COMPRAS GENERALES";

fac.FacturaRecibida.DesgloseFactura = new DesgloseFacturaRecibidasType();

DetalleIVARecibidaType[] tipoivas = new DetalleIVARecibidaType[1];
DetalleIVARecibidaType tipoiva = new DetalleIVARecibidaType();
tipoiva.BaseImponible = "1000";
tipoiva.TipoImpositivo = "21";
tipoiva.CuotaSoportada = "210";
tipoivas[0] = tipoiva;
fac.FacturaRecibida.DesgloseFactura.DesgloseIVA = tipoivas;

LRFacturasRecibidasType[] facturas = new LRFacturasRecibidasType[1];
facturas[0] = fac;
servicio.RegistroLRFacturasRecibidas = facturas;
siiSOAPClient enviar = new siiSOAPClient();
RespuestaLRFRecibidasType respuesta = new RespuestaLRFRecibidasType();
enviar.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = oCert;

**(( Aqui es donde me da el error ))**
respuesta = enviar.SuministroLRFacturasRecibidas(servicio);

string cResp = respuesta.EstadoEnvio.ToString().ToUpper();
```

En mi app.config tengo esto

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>

<appSettings>
</appSettings>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="siiBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="siiBinding1">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="siiBinding2" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="siiBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                <httpsTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding"
            contract="WsSiiFraEmi.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" />
        <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fr/SiiFactFRV1SOAP"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding1"
            contract="WsSiiFraRec.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactRecibidasPruebas" />

</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Gracias por tu ayuda. :-)

Comment: Hola, revisa que el certificado obtenido es correcto y es válido para firmar el envío a la AEAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he resuelto el error que te da a tí, pero tengo otro error de comunicación SSL/TLS. Te pego mi código para que mires lo del tema del certificado:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "siiBinding";
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = 
HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

FacturasEmitidas.siiSOAPClient Servicio = new 
FacturasEmitidas.siiSOAPClient("SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas", new EndpointAddress("https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"));
Servicio.Endpoint.Binding = binding;                        

Servicio.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = 
cFunciones.EncontrarCertificado(DatosEnvio.NombreCertificado);
Servicio.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = true; Servicio.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(GrupoFacturasAEAT.FacturasAltas.Facturas);
```

Comment: Hola Diego, buenas
Pongo aquí la misma respuesta que me has dicho por si sirve para más gente...


System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)

Answer (score 2):

En el app.config, el siiBinding1 no has añadido el transport.

```
        <binding name="siiBinding1">
            *<security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
            </security>*
        </binding>
```

Espero que te funcione, saludos.

Comment: Pero que ciego he estado.... Muuuuchas gracias... JML. Te debo una.... :-)