# Error en servicio web SII (Suministro Inmediato de Información)

Tags: c#, vb.net, webservice, aeat-sii

Buenos días.

Estoy desarrollando el módulo para conectar al SII. Hago el desarrollo en VB.NET con Visual Studio 2015. Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error en los envíos

> El tipo de contenido text/html del mensaje de respuesta no coincide con el tipo de contenido del enlace (text/xml; charset=utf-8). Si usa un codificador personalizado, asegúrese de que el método IsContentTypeSupported se implemente correctamente.

El problema es que se espera una respuesta en formato XML y recibo HTML como consecuencia de un error en el servicio web al que llamo. Creo que este error, por lo que he consultado por Internet, está producido por el certificado digital.

Dispongo de un certificado válido. Así hago la carga del mismo

```
Dim cert As New X509Certificate2(pathCertificado)
oFactEmitidas.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert
oFactEmitidas.ClientCredentials.UseIdentityConfiguration = True
```

El mismo objeto oFactEmitidas lo uso para realizar el envio

```
oRespuesta = oFactEmitidas.SuministroLRFacturasEmitidas(oSfe)
```

El archivo de configuración app.Config es el siguiente:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="siiBinding">
                  <security mode="Transport">
                      <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
                  </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="siiBinding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="siiBinding"
                      contract="swFactEmitida.siiSOAP" name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Ya he visto preguntas con el mismo error, pero he aplicado las soluciones y no me han funcionado.

¿Que es lo que se me escapa?

Un saludo a todos
Justo

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. La pregunta está bien tal cual, pero si añades (brevemente, o quizás con un link a la pregunta) las soluciones que ya has intentado, evitarás que la gente te proporcione las mismas respuestas.

Comment: Gracias por la bienvenida @SJuan76. Aplique la solución de la pregunta [Error consumiendo servicio web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67566/siisuministro-inmediato-de-informaci%C3%B3n-webservice-en-facturas-recibidas?rq=1)  y no me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes.

Problema resuelto. La solución ha sido cambiar el certificado. Resulta que solo son válidos los certificados con extensión .pfx o .p12. Los archivos con extensión .cer o .crt son formatos de exportación de clave pública de certificados y no son válidos.

Un saludo a todos
Justo